# itertools and selection from partitioned sets

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list of lists, which we can think of as 3 urns with 3 balls.

```
mylist= [
            ['HIGH_1', 'MED_1', 'LOW_1'],
            ['HIGH_2', 'MED_2', 'LOW_2'],
            ['HIGH_3', 'MED_3', 'LOW_3']
        ]
```

I'm only allowed to select one ball from each urn.
I would like to get all combinations of 1 ball, 2 balls, and 3 balls. Answer in  a list of lists.

In order to achieve this I place a fake element (None) in each *urn*

```
mylist= [
            [None, 'HIGH_1', 'MED_1', 'LOW_1'],
            [None, 'HIGH_2', 'MED_2', 'LOW_2'],
            [None, 'HIGH_3', 'MED_3', 'LOW_3']
           ]
```

Now the following use of itertools and filter gets me the desired solution.

```
combos = []
for l in itertools.product(*mylist):
    combos.append(filter(lambda a: a is not None, l))

combos.remove(())   # remove the empty element
print [list(elem) for elem in combos]


[['HIGH_3'], ['MED_3'], ['LOW_3'], ... , ['MED_2', 'HIGH_3'], ['MED_2', 'MED_3'], ['MED_1', 'HIGH_3'], ..., ['LOW_1', 'LOW_2', 'MED_3'], ['LOW_1', 'LOW_2', 'LOW_3']]
```

Which produces 63 elements.

9 (single elements) + 27 (two elements) + 27 (three elements)  = 63

Adding in that fake *None* and post filtering doesn't feel like the best way to do this.

Is there a way to avoid those two seemingly redundant steps?

Comment: So what have you written, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Do you have criteria for *"better"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following generator

```
def combos(data):
    for i in xrange(1, len(data) + 1):
        for item in itertools.combinations(data, i):
            for j in itertools.product(*item):
                yield j
```

Probably the most pythonic solution I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `remove()` when you append only non-empty items. You can also skip the last list comprehension by converting items to list right after filter.

```
import itertools
import pprint

mylist= [
            [None, 'HIGH_1', 'MED_1', 'LOW_1'],
            [None, 'HIGH_2', 'MED_2', 'LOW_2'],
            [None, 'HIGH_3', 'MED_3', 'LOW_3']
           ]
combos = []
for item in itertools.product(*mylist):
    combo = list(filter(lambda a: a is not None, item))
    if combo:
        combos.append(combo)

pprint.pprint(combos)
```

**UPDATE**

Manually inserting `None` is not nice. Adding one line that does this in a list comprehension:

```
import itertools
import pprint

mylist= [
            ['HIGH_1', 'MED_1', 'LOW_1'],
            ['HIGH_2', 'MED_2', 'LOW_2'],
            ['HIGH_3', 'MED_3', 'LOW_3']
           ]

mylist_with_nones = [[None] + item for item in mylist]
combos = []
for item in itertools.product(*mylist_with_nones):
    combo = list(filter(lambda a: a is not None, item))
    if combo:
        combos.append(combo)

pprint.pprint(combos)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, that helps, I was hoping to not have to add the three None values into my arrays. Look at the first mylist object. Can you get the desired result with that object without having to add a None into each array?

Comment: You don't have to add the `None` entries by hand. I updated my answer and added a line that does this for you.